# BxSlider multiple slideshows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I have 2 custom slideshows in same page but they can't work together, a slideshow it works but another slideshow doesn't. Im already read the example of multiple slideshow [IN HERE](http://bxslider.com/examples/multiple-slideshows) but my custom slideshows dont work like what i want. 
here's [MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qLSGe/72/)

here's my HTML :

```
<div class="show_mob_product" id="showbrand1">
<ul class="bxslider" id="slider1">
<li>
     <img src="http://lh4.ggpht.com/siuzB88608t3t3_BvoIF60VPtTvc7MfSbX5dBYWhVNsR8hPGZPm3O56CXfvobL83gRyXyhyJ2Hx4--1_EMDFdWO5lJLOjmV8vTiJp6hi" />
    <div>I hope it's work</div>
    <br>
</li>
   <li>
     <img src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/jAOnlgoz-lK2LdYvlYY2xfC3Aa1K1v3DAwb95T5uYRPfwIAxljXl5EXc9DCpitmxbknH4YtE2mCSrZLIRVnJgF3kUxRRR0kXNWifQVRw" />
    <div>I hope it's solved</div>
    <br>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="outside">
<p><span id="slider-prev"></span>  <span id="slider-next"></span>

</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="show_mob_product" id="showbrand2">
<ul class="bxslider" id="slider1">
<li>
    <img src="http://lh4.ggpht.com/siuzB88608t3t3_BvoIF60VPtTvc7MfSbX5dBYWhVNsR8hPGZPm3O56CXfvobL83gRyXyhyJ2Hx4--1_EMDFdWO5lJLOjmV8vTiJp6hi" />
    <div>I hope it's work</div>
    <br>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/jAOnlgoz-lK2LdYvlYY2xfC3Aa1K1v3DAwb95T5uYRPfwIAxljXl5EXc9DCpitmxbknH4YtE2mCSrZLIRVnJgF3kUxRRR0kXNWifQVRw" />
    <div>I hope it's solved</div>
    <br>
  </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="outside">
  <p><span id="slider-prev2"></span>  <span id="slider-next2"></span>

  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and my javascript :

```
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    nextSelector: '#slider-next',
    prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
    controls: true,
    pager: false,
    nextText: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TZDsPC0.png" height="25" width="25"/>',
    prevText: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/AKjTWvT.png" height="25" width="25"/>'
});
$('#slider2').bxSlider({
    nextSelector: '#slider-next2',
    prevSelector: '#slider-prev2',
    controls: true,
    pager: false,
    nextText: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TZDsPC0.png" height="25" width="25"/>',
    prevText: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/AKjTWvT.png" height="25" width="25"/>'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI now you define Two ul

and both ul id is same

```
<ul class="bxslider" id="slider1">
```

Now do this

**now define different** id first ul id is   `<ul class="bxslider" id="slider1">`

second ul id is `<ul class="bxslider" id="slider2">`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qLSGe/74/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicate IDs

```
<ul class="bxslider" id="slider1">
```